# Swift update storyboard direction after changing Localize language

Tags: ios, swift, language-switching

I am new to Swift and I am trying to change the application views direction from LTR to RTL when the user click Arabic language button. 
So far I have this code below and all the text changed correctly unless the direction. The direction works only if I closed and reopened the application. 
Please help

```
@IBAction func goToLanguage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let availableLanguages = Localize.availableLanguages()

    actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Switch Language", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    for language in availableLanguages {
        let displayName = Localize.displayNameForLanguage(language)
        let langString = language as String

        if(langString != "Base"){

            let languageAction = UIAlertAction(title: displayName, style: .Default, handler: {
                (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                Localize.setCurrentLanguage(language)

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject([language], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                delegate.refreshEverything()

            })
            actionSheet.addAction(languageAction) 
        }
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    })

    actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force UIView direction without closing the app.
For arabic language add the code below to change direction :

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

and for french or english language use :

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```